# Calculate breakout bands of Elliott wave oscillator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, trading

I am trying to calculate the values for the Elliott oscillator breakbands in python. I have the indicator logic in C#, which I will leave below.
In python I have already calculated and checked the value of the histogram, on which depends the calculation of the breakbands I want to calculate.

However, the values that the current logic gives are not the correct ones and I can't find what is the fault, since as I mentioned, I am replicating an existing logic in another language.

[image: Image EWO Example]

Actual logic in Python:

```py
# For LowerBand, this return directly 0:
osc_fast = 5
osc_slow = 35
lens = osc_fast + osc_slow
pr = 2 / lens
strenght = 100
            
df = df.assign(Lwr_Line=0)
df['Lwr_Line'] = np.where(df["EWO_Std"] < 0, (df['EWO_Std']*pr) + (df['Lwr_Line'].shift(1)*(1-pr)), df['Lwr_Line'].shift(1))
df['LineEWOLwr'] = strenght / 100 * df['Lwr_Line']
df.drop(columns='Lwr_Line', inplace=True)

# For UpperBand:
            
df = df.assign(Upr_Line=0)
df['Upr_Line'] = np.where(df["EWO_Std"] > 0, (df['EWO_Std']*pr) + (df['Upr_Line'].shift(1)*(1-pr)), df['Upr_Line'].shift(1))
df['LineEWOUpr'] = strenght / 100 * df['Upr_Line']
df.drop(columns='Upr_Line', inplace=True)
```

Logic checked in C#:

```cs
{
            
            MP[0]       =   ( High[0] + Low[0] ) / 2;
            
            UprLine[0]  =   0;
            LwrLine[0]  =   0;
            Lens        =   OscFast + OscSlow;
            Pr = 2.0/Lens; 

            if(CurrentBar < OscSlow){
                OscAG = 0;
                if (OscAG > 0){
                    OscAGUpr[0] = OscAG;
                    if (OscAGUpr[0] > OscAGUpr[1]){
                        OscAGUprDiv[0] = OscAG;
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    OscAGLwr[0] = OscAG;
                    OscAGLwrDiv[0] = OscAG;             
                }
            }
            
            else{
                OscAG   =   SMA(MP,OscFast)[0] - SMA(MP,OscSlow)[0];
                if (OscAG > 0){
                        UprLine[0]  = (OscAG*Pr) + (UprLine[1]*(1-Pr));
                        LwrLine[0]  = LwrLine[1];
                    OscAGUpr[0] = OscAG;
                        if (OscAGUpr[0] > OscAGUpr[1])
                            {
                                OscAGUprDiv[0] = OscAG;
                            }

                }
                else{
                    UprLine[0]      = UprLine[1];
                    LwrLine[0]      = (OscAG*Pr) + (LwrLine[1]*(1-Pr));
                    OscAGLwr[0]     = OscAG;
                        if (OscAGLwr[0] > OscAGLwr[1])
                        {
                            OscAGLwrDiv[0] = OscAG;
                        }   
                        
                }
            }
            
            LineEWOUpr[0]   =   BOBStrength / 100 * UprLine[0];
            LineEWOLwr[0]   =   BOBStrength / 100 * LwrLine[0];
            
            
        }
```

Does anyone know what the error could be?

Thanks!

I'm tried many combinations, but no one works

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Anybody? Please